# Increase performance of my WPF progressbar usercontrol

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, user-controls, graphic

I just wanted to make an simple cirling progressbar but using rekurive algorithm. 
It is that easy but does hurt the Designer and does not perform well.

[image: Circling progressbar]

I do not understand why it does not. 
Please, can you download the sourcecode and check where you made changes to improve performance?

Download project sourcecode here:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B4LQ40lENyTQZDViY2UwNTYtZTczMC00OGNjLTkxYjAtMmI3N2E3YTdhODM3&hl=en_US

I am not interested in getting a progressbar but in why does it not perform.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the compositor thread?

Have you tried using the regular progress bar in the same place? I'd bet it has the same performance problems.

The silverlight team released a toolkit

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

And it contains a progress bar. The biggest difference is that it runs on the compositor thread. That might speed up your problems. Take a look at the source code for the silverlight toolkit to see how they did it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not interested in getting a progressbar but in why does it not perform.

Comment: He is not suggesting it as a replacement but as a control to test against

Comment: @jk is correct. The default progress bar has horrible performance problems, mostly because it runs on the UI thread. So any time the UI is doing anything, performance sucks. Putting the progress bar on the compositor thread makes it much more performant. Updated answer for clarity.